# delete and edit in jquery grid struts2

Tags: json, jqgrid, struts2

i passed two days trying to add delete and edit links to a jqgrid using json and struts2 but in vain.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteLinkFormatter(cellval, options, rowObject, icon, link_class, link_action) {
    return "<a href='deleteEleve?eleveId="+cellval+"' onClick='javascript: return delete_eleve()'><font class='hyperlink'><u>Delete</u></font></a>";  
}
function delete_eleve() {
    var agree=confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?");
    if (agree){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

i really spend too much time to fix this problem,if any one can help i will be grateful.
i have seen this links http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and this http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action but nothing goes fine.:s

```
<s:url id="remoteurl" value="/eleve/eleveTable.action"/>
<s:url id="deleteurl" action="deleteEleve" />
<sjg:grid id="gridtable"
        caption="Editer Eleves"
        dataType="json"
        width="755"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        rowList="5,10,15,20"
        rowNum="5"
        rownumbers="true"
        multiselect="true"
        navigator="true"
        navigatorView="false"
        navigatorDelete="false"
        navigatorAdd="false"
        navigatorRefresh="false"
        navigatorSearch="false"
        navigatorEditOptions="{width:600,height:400,reloadAfterSubmit:false}"
        navigatorEdit="true"
        editurl="%{editurl}"

    >
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveId" title="Eleve Id" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveNom" index="eleveNom" title="Eleve Nom" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="true"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="elevePrenom" index="elevePrenom" title="Eleve Prenom" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveCne" index="eleveCne" title="Eleve Cne" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveAdresse" index="eleveAdresse" title="Eleve Adresse" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveDatenaissance" index="eleveDatenaissance" title="Datenaissance" editable="true" edittype="date" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="anneEnregistrement" index="anneEnregistrement" title="Anne Enregistrement" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="membreClub" index="membreClub" title="Membre Club" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="id_classe" index="id_classe" title="classe" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>

  <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveId" index="EleveId" title="Delete Eleve"
                            sortable="true" formatter="deleteLinkFormatter" /> 

</sjg:grid>
```